# How do I convert ObjectId to string after find()?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have this example of an object in a `movies` collection:

```
{
    "_id":{"$oid":"5f5101c31a05d8a343f944b1"},
    "title":"Mother to Earth",
    "year":2020,
    "description":"A group of simps tries to find the source of an obscure meme game.",
    "screenings":
        [
            {
                "screeningID":{"$oid":"5f5101c31a05d8a343f944b0"},
                "timedate":"2020-09-29, 18:00PM",
                "tickets":46
            }
        ]
}
```

And I want this to be the output of a `find()` function, with `title` as the query. However, when I include `_id` and `screeningID`, I get a `TypeError: Object of type ObjectId is not JSON serializable` error. I need the `screeningID`'s value, in order to use it in a later part of my code, and preferably as a `string`. How do I do that?

EDIT: Here are the two lines of code in question:

```
result = movies.find_one({'title':data['title']})
result = {'title': result['title'],"year": result['year'],'description': result['description'],'screenings': [result['screenings']]}
```

I skipped the conditional checks I had in there, for simplicity's sake. As is, this produces the error I showed above. The only solution is to add `{'_id':0, 'screenings.screeningID':0}` in the projection of the first line, but this means losing the `ObjectId`s, and especially `screeningID`, which I need for later.

Comment: Show us your code!

Comment: Done! Do you have any more questions?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and got no errors. If you run this do you get any errors?

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson import ObjectId

data = {
    "_id": ObjectId("5f5101c31a05d8a343f944b1"),
    "title":"Mother to Earth",
    "year":2020,
    "description":"A group of simps tries to find the source of an obscure meme game.",
    "screenings":
        [
            {
                "screeningID": ObjectId("5f5101c31a05d8a343f944b0"),
                "timedate":"2020-09-29, 18:00PM",
                "tickets":46
            }
        ]
}

db = MongoClient(port=27019)['testdatabase']
db.testcollection.delete_many({})

db.testcollection.insert_one(data)

result = db.testcollection.find_one({'title':data['title']})
result = {'title': result['title'],"year": result['year'],'description': result['description'],'screenings': [result['screenings']]}
```

Comment: It works when done independently from the intended function like this, but when I try and do the same where I need it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok so either take the example code and use it in your code, or post a similar code sample where it's not working.